# How to get text into groups according to their HTML structure?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am dealing with such html processing problem，to get the text into groups according to their structure .The original file is very complex ,so I simplified it like below :
I have get the name list :['Json Bell','Jim Charlie','Mike Alfie','William Cyphort','Juniper Egbert']

and the html file :

```
 <p>studets</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Json Bell</li>
      <li>Jim Charlie</li>
      <li>Mike Alfie</li> 
    </ul>
    <p>teachers</p>
    <ul>
      <li>William Cyphort</li>
      <li>Juniper Egbert</li>
    </ul>
```

How can I get the groups['Json Bell','Jim Charlie','Mike Alfie'],['William Cyphort','Juniper Egbert']

Any Idea would be welcomed! I am familiar with python ,so processing method in python would be much better.

The question can be described in another way :how can I know whether the strings have the same parent nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this problem I would use list comprehension - firstly select all `<ul>` tags and then for each `ul` tag select all `li` tags and extract the text:

```
data = """
 <p>studets</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Json Bell</li>
      <li>Jim Charlie</li>
      <li>Mike Alfie</li>
    </ul>
    <p>teachers</p>
    <ul>
      <li>William Cyphort</li>
      <li>Juniper Egbert</li>
    </ul>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

print([[li.text for li in ul.select('li')] for ul in soup.select('ul')])
```

Output is:

```
[['Json Bell', 'Jim Charlie', 'Mike Alfie'], ['William Cyphort', 'Juniper Egbert']]
```

**EDIT:**

For comparing parents you can use `.parent` property:

```
tag1 = soup.find(text='Json Bell')
tag2 = soup.find(text='Jim Charlie')

print(tag1.parent == tag2.parent)   #tag1 and tag2 parents are <li> tags (different)
print(tag1.parent.parent == tag2.parent.parent)   #this compares <ul> tags, which are the same
```

This prints:

```
False
True
```

Note: `soup.find(text='Json Bell')` finds `NavigableString` class. The parent of this `NavigableString` is `<li>` tag. The parent of `<li>` tag is `<ul>` tag and so on...

Comment: The situation can be much complex, so I change my quesiton :how to know the strings how the same parent node.